# R shiny how to pass authentication from another App

Tags: authentication, shiny, saml, shiny-server

How can authentication details be passed to a shiny app in a a secure way?

The shiny app is hosted on a a Linux machine with Shiny Server (Open Source version) and should only be accessible after login on another webpage (through SAML) which is hosted on another Linux machine. The shiny app should have different functionality, depending on user rights. So, that information has to be passed to the shiny app at startup.

How can this be achieved in a secure and reliable way?

The only options I could think of were:

1. Getting the IP-adress of the user and making a request from the other webpage to get the user-rights of that IP.
2. Passing user-rights within the URL params and using those with `parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)` at shiny-startup.

The first option would make the app depend on a third-party service that gives me the IP and I dont know how a proxy, Vpn etc would interfer with this approach and how reliable it would be. The second option doesn't really seem secure or professional.

What other options would there be?

Comment: what option did you choose? I am facing the same problem. I am thinking that best option would be: A) to use encrypted token generated on main website and decrypt it on shiny from sessions$client $data but would be secure only with limited session time (specified within the token) and upon post request so token sharing will be limited... B) if you can query the database of the main server. Create unique usage Auth token in database for user upon login, shiny would then validate token. When token validation test is performed the token is removed.... Well, seems overly complicated.

Comment: We are currently using a cookie-based approach. The user logs in on a different site which creates a cookie and as soon as he comes to the shiny app the cookie is retrieved and passed back to a servlet which returns user and userrights. Not the most elegant solution, as the user has the log in twice in the end (although invisibly on the shiny app) but still nicer and more secure than the 2 approaches listed in my question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Will try the cookie next time. I ended up using a one-off authentication token in GET parameter.  Token generated from main website. Then shiny validate token with DB and retrieves users rights/name. In validation step, token is removed so cannot be used twice. If token is wrong Shiny redirect to error page.